# How to query for null in nested db_or conditional

Tags: database

I am trying to perform a query as listed below (notice the check for NULL)

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
/* add fields and joins... */
$query->condition(db_or()
      ->condition(db_and()
                  ->condition('join_alias1.field_date_unassigned_value', NULL, 'IS')
                  ->condition('join_alias2.field_date_assigned_value', $end_date, '<='))
      ->condition(db_and()
                  ->condition('join_alias1.field_date_unassigned_value', $start_date, '>=')
                  ->condition('join_alias2.field_date_assigned_or_submitted_value', $end_date, '<=')));
```

I am aware that Drupal expects Null values to be checked like

```
$query->isNull('myfield');
```

But I don't understand how to perform a query like I listed above while using `$query->isNull()`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `isNull()` in the `db_and()` condition, it'll work just fine:

```
$query->condition(db_or()
  ->condition(db_and()
    ->isNull('join_alias1.field_date_unassigned_value')
    ->condition('join_alias2.field_date_assigned_value', $end_date, '<=')
  )
  ->condition(db_and()
    ->condition('join_alias1.field_date_unassigned_value', $start_date, '>=')
    ->condition('join_alias2.field_date_assigned_or_submitted_value', $end_date, '<=')
  )
);
```